# In bash, what's the diff between [[ test1 && test2 ]] vs [[ test1 ]] && [[ test2 ]]

Tags: bash

What's the difference, if any, in the following two bash evaluations:

```
if [[ -s $file1 && $file1 -nt $file2 ]]; then

if [[ -s $file1 ]] && [[ $file1 -nt $file2 ]]; then
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. They're functionally identical.

---

An interesting aside, if you used `[` instead of `[[`, there actually is a detectable difference cause by the order of evaluation:

```
[ -s "$file1" -a "$file1" -nt "$(echo side effect >&2)" ] 

[ -s "$file1" ] && [ "$file1" -nt "$(echo side effect >&2)" ]
```

In this case, the first line would print "side effect" while the second would not.

Again, however, this is only the case for `[` and not for `[[ ]]`.